# Pure JS. How to add event listener for submit any form

Tags: javascript, pure-js

i tried to addEventListener once for  all forms on page to serialize and check them before ajax sending. If you have an pill for my broken head, share it pls

```
window.addEventListener('submit', function(e){

        //Serialize Form
        //Ajax send

    }, false);
```

thx much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query all forms and add event listener to each item:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('test');
}, false));
```

```html
<form>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```